# Saber los registros que devuelve un mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, php7

Cómo puedo saber la cantidad de registros que devuelve `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Adjunto el código que tengo.

```
$sql4 = "SELECT * curso";
mysqli_select_db($bd, 'bdaita');
$result4 = $bd->query($sql4);
if (!$result4) {
  die('No ha sido posible conectarse a la BD: ' . mysqli_error($bd));
}
  while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apoyate del método `num_rows` con el cual en teoría no necesitas del método `fetch array` pues no quieres generar un arreglo de los datos ya que solo obtendrás una celda conteniendo el total de registros

Lo anterior por qué al usar el bucle `while` y además pasando el argumento `MYSQLI_ASSOC` pides que tus datos sean en forma de array asociativo y estas trayendo todos los valores de las columnas.

Entonces alcanza con

```
$total = $result4->num_rows;
echo $total;
```